# Data reshape and grouping

Tags: r, string, reshape

I'm  new to R, please help.
I have a data frame with 5 column with names Seasondate and V1, V2,V3, V4.
The season dates have different format of dates and are around 1000 observations like:

```
January to March 
August to October 
05/01/2013 to 10/30/2013
NA
February to June 
02/15/2013 to 06/19/2013
```

I would like to bring all of them into one format. Like bringing them them into all in one format of Month to Month.

Parsing with string functions would be highly appreciated

**Edit 1:**

All of them have the same year of 2013 
Thanks

Comment: 1.) Do all observations happen in the same year? 2.) Is it possible to identify all of the possible formats?

Comment: Yes all ot them have the same year of 2013

Comment: In the example you provided there are only two formats `Month1 to Month2` and `Month1/Day1/Year1 to Month2/Day2/Year2`. Are they the only formats in the real data?

Comment: Oh yes they have just these two formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another idea that doesn't use date coercion, but uses the `month.name` vector from base R.

```
## change the column to character
df$V1 <- as.character(df$V1)
## find the numeric values
g <- grepl("\\d", df$V1)
## split them, get the months, then apply 'month.name' and paste
df$V1[g] <- vapply(strsplit(df$V1[g], " to "), function(x) {
    paste(month.name[as.integer(sub("/.*", "", x))], collapse = " to ")
}, "")
```

Resulting in

```
df
                 V1
1  January to March
2 August to October
3    May to October
4              <NA>
5  February to June
6  February to June
```

**Original Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, NA, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("02/15/2013 to 06/19/2013", 
"05/01/2013 to 10/30/2013", "August to October", "February to June", 
"January to March"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Awesome , thank you very much 

Just curious, if i want to convert all to month/year in numeric like 
Feb to Dec --> 02 to 12, how should I edit it ?
Change the format month.name as.numeric ?

Answer (score 2):

Do some formatting back and forth using `as.Date` and `format`, then `paste` it all together again:

```
datext <- function(x) {
  dates <- as.Date(x,format="%m/%d/%Y")
  if(all(is.na(dates))) x else format(dates,"%B")
}
vapply(
  lapply(strsplit(as.character(dat$Seasondate), " to "), datext), 
  paste, collapse=" to ", FUN.VALUE=character(1)
)
#[1] "January to March"  "August to October" "May to October"    
#[4] "NA"                "February to June"  "February to June"
```